# Accessing Form Elements Dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

In my winforms application I create form elements(Radiobutton, Label etc.) dynamically. I need to access specific form element with its name property. A simple solution is iterate each form element using Form1.Controls and check its name property. But in my opinion this solution is not effective. Is it possible to access specific form element using reflection?

Comment: Can you give an argument why do you think that iterating children is less effective than reflection?

Comment: If you are using .Net4 there is an overload of Controls indexer: form1.Controls["ControlName"]

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the controls collection you can use the Find() method provided

```
myForm.Controls.Find("ControlName",true);
```

If you know its type - you can cast it as well

```
TextBox t = (TextBox)myForm.controls.Find("txtFirstName",false);
```

The true or false will instruct the function to search for any child controls.